# .htaccess mod_rewrite - how to "priority" rules - not direct file

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I got some mod_rewrite in apache .htaccess:

```
RewriteRule (.*)?([0-9]+)?\.(jpg)$ mademe.php?file=$2.jpg [QSA,NC,L]
```

my-picture-123.jpg (this is "wirtual" file) > mademe.php?file=123.jpg (this is "real" file on serwer) -> it is OK > it generates and return new file based on 123.jpg

but if somebody pass in browser: 123.jpg it show this 123.jpg (not new generated file)

- how to prevent to display this "real" images on serwer, how to add to RewriteRule first priority?

Comment: Is the first part of the virtual file, consistent? or does the name always change?

Comment: 123.jpg extsts, I want to create new filebased 123.jpg, id file name is diffrent ex. aaa-bbb_123.jpg itis ok.

Comment: Can you show your full .htaccess? Also tell what is full URL you're using?